# Counting Lattice Points

Tags: elementary-number-theory, complex-numbers, integer-lattices

Lattice points are of great importance. I encountered a problem as follows:- given a circle of radius 'r' as x²+y²=r² the number of lattice points can take values . The options were (0,72,69,140). I tried the problem using complex numbers but couldn't figure out a short and sweet method to tackle the problem so I need help ! Please help me!

Comment: Are you counting the lattice points inside the circle, or the the lattice points on the circle itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint, if you believe that exactly one of the 4 given choices is correct: the center of the circle is a lattice point, and has a property all the other lattice points lack.

Comment: A great hint. Even though we (ideally) stll need to perform a reality check given that there are two different sizes for the non-trivial orbits of $D_4$.

Comment: Can I do something like n=(complex prime factorisation) and then use  some combinatorics to end up at 4(pi(sigma{X(i^r)})) and thanks for the hint

Comment: Do you mean use Gauss integers factorization ?

Comment: Do we agree that your lattice is $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ with center at the origin ?

Comment: Yes.  The number of lattice points inside the circle must be odd: the origin plus twice the number of pairs of non-zero lattice points $\pm\lambda$.